# VS cannot debug referenced class library after I made an update to it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I've got two projects in my solution. Number one is a class library and the second one a console app.

The reference worked fine before, and I could debug the code in the class library when running the console app. But it stopped working after I've made a change (changes to methods) in the class lib. Now the debugger won't attach in the class lib. I can debug my console app.

I've tried to remove/add the reference (after a new build) but no luck.

It seems to reference an old dll. But I've checked the path to the reference and it points to bin/Debug in my class library project and the date matches when I re-built the class library.

Someone knows why this is happening?

Comment: clean ,rebuild, restart or just use the backup file

Comment: an advice always create a backupfile with date as a name at the end of everyday work so u can get out of situations like this

Comment: Yeah, didn't expect this and should be easy to solve? Will do a backup from here on.. :) I will try clean, rebuild and restart.

Comment: Didn't work with clean, rebuild and restart :(

Comment: go for backups then they will sort out as a last option & remember to create backups

Comment: But should I copy the dll from the class lib/bin/debug to my console app after every update and reference that dll instead, is that what you mean?

Comment: do u have any backups?if not i dont know what to do .

Comment: No I don't have any backups. I've the class library as a project in my solution.

Comment: @Robin, What about this issue? Would you please share us the latest information about this issue? Please delete the bin\debug folder for your console app, and set the property copy local=true for your class library reference, and then rebuild your two project, debug it again. Of course, please make sure that two projects use the same .NET Framework version and platform target in your side. If you get any latest information, please feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

> Someone knows why this is happening?

Did you **rebuild** your class library project after you made a change (changes to methods) in the class lib? If not, that is the reason why you get this issue.

When you add the reference and make it points to bin/Debug in the class library project, the debugger will be easy to access the .pdb file in that path. However, if you made any change in the class lib without rebuild the project, the old .pdb file will not match the source code. So the debugger won't access in the class lib due to the mismatch .pdb file.

To resolve this issue, you should **rebuild your class library project** after made any modification in the class lib. Or you can just **add the reference by** **Project-Reference** rathan than Browse. In this case, Visual Studio will rebuild the referenced project automatically before debugging.